# Continuous map on space of Schwarz functions

Tags: distribution-theory, schwartz-space

I am studying distribution theory, specifically the Schwarz space of rapidly decaying functions and its dual, the space of tempered distributions. One of my my problem involves proving that

> The map $(1+x^2)^v \times:\phi(x) \rightarrow (1+x^2)^v\phi(x)$ is a linear and continuous map on $S(\mathbb{R})$ and $S'(\mathbb{R})$.

In order to do this, I need to prove that

i) $(1+x^2)^v\phi(x) \in S(\mathbb{R}), (S'(\mathbb{R}), \text{respectively})$ (done due to the fact that the derivative of $(1+x^2)^v$ is just a polynomial)

ii) $(1+x^2)^v \times$ is linear (clear)

iii) $(1+x^2)^v \times$ is continuous (seems intuitive but not so clear to me)

How do I prove that a map on $S(\mathbb{R})$ (and $S'(\mathbb{R})$) is continuous? I know that $C^\infty(\Omega)$ is a Frechet space, equipped with a series of semi-norms given by $f_n = \Sigma_{\alpha \leq n} \sup_{x\in K_n}|\partial^\alpha u(x)|$ for $u\in C^\infty(\Omega)$, and the equipped metric distance is $d(u,v) = \Sigma_{n=0}^{+\infty}2^{-n}\frac{f_n}{1+f_n}$.

I have tried to use the definitions of continuous map between topological spaces, i.e, the pre-image of an open set is open but it does not seem possible.

Can you help me with this exercise please?

Comment: Prove that $f_n$ of the image of $\phi$ is $\le$ some constant times $f_n$ of $\phi.$

Comment: @AnneBauval oh yes, I can deduce that simply by using the definitions of $f_n$ together with the Leibniz formula. What about the case of $S'(\mathcal(R))$? Do we have the same idea? For Frechet spaces in general, can we use this same scheme of proving continuity?

Comment: The topology on S' is that of poinwise convergence on S so you are done. And for general Frechet instead of S, same idea but not necessarily with the same seminorm. And even same idea for a linear map from a Frechet to another one.

Comment: Thank you very much @AnneBauval

Comment: @AnneBauval: The weak-star topology is rather pathological, the proper topology to use on spaces of distributions like $S'$ is the strong dual topology.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam (and QuangDũngĐinh) Then let us say that the map is continuous on $S'$ by the same argument as in my first comment.

Comment: Sure. One can also use a general result about transpose maps $S'\rightarrow S'$ being continuous for strong dual topologies if the underlying map $S\rightarrow S$ is continuous for the Frechet topologies.

Comment: Thank you for replying! Can you recommend me a textbook/lecture notes about the topic of distributions specifically? My teacher provides me his hand written note, but it is not so clear for a beginner level. Thank you in advance!